# Logarithmic regression in Microsoft Excel

Tags: regression, excel, logarithm

With reference to this regression line:

[image: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/46186972/regression_line.gif]

As shown in the bottom-right of this chart, the formula for the black regression line is:

```
y = 0.075ln(x) + 0.2775
```

How can I write this formula in Microsoft Excel, so that I can calculate y for any given value of x? (I tried calculating it using Excel help, however it did not give me the correct y values shown in the regression line chart linked above. But this could well be because I know little about regressions and nothing about logarithms.)

Comment: From a statistical point of view, the line doesn't look very good to me. Almost all the points on the right side are below the line. The line should go through the center of them.

Answer (score 2):

Let's say you have a column of numbers in column `B`, which represent your x values. They start on row `2` and go through row `11`.  Then, in column `C` row `2` you write `=ln(B2)` and drag that down to `C11`.  In column `D` row `2` you write `=0.075*C2` and drag that down to `D11`.  Finally, in column `E` row `2` you write `=D2+0.2775` and drag that down to `E11`.  When you're done, the predicted y values for each x value will be in column `E`.  The predicted y value in a given row of `E` will correspond to the x value in that same row in column `B`.

This way you can see the calculation unfolding.  If you prefer to do it in one formula, you would write `=0.075*ln(B2)+0.2775` in column `C` row `2` and drag it down to `C11`.